# How to integrate a proxy program in nodejs and redirect localhost:5000/api to localhost:5001

Tags: node.js

In my project, a nodejs and asp.net core webapi exist together. the clientApp use http://localhost:5000 to access, and the asp.net core webapi backend use http://localhost:5001 to access. When there is a backend request http://localhost:5000/api, we want to redict it to http://localhost:5001 directly.

From Phil and Ninezero90hy suggestion, I have used  http-proxy-middleware to setup a proxy js, and use command node to execute it seperatly. It works fine.

proxy.js

```
//proxy setup by using express framework
const express = require('express');
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

const app = express();
app.use(
    '/api',
    createProxyMiddleware({
        target: 'http://localhost:5001',
        changeOrigin: true,
        logLevel: 'debug',
        pathRewrite: {
            '^/api': 'http://localhost:5001/api',
        },
    }),
);
app.listen(5000);
```

I want to integrate this program into my project, I found I can't do it directly. When I startup the web project, the command 'npm run dev' is executed, and it is different with node command enviorement. How can I make the proxy program into it. Could someone make any suggestion here. Thanks!

Comment: You mean like [http-proxy-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-middleware)

Comment: @Phil,Thanks, I will try to use this middleware.

Answer (score 1):

For example

```json
{
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.4"
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

or

```bash
npm install -D http-proxy-middleware
```

or

```bash
yarn add http-proxy-middleware --dev
```

`↑` These three methods produce the same results.

Add the `SetupProxy.js` file to the `src` child.

```js
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use(
    '/api/boards',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://localhost:5001',
      changeOrigin: true,
      logLevel: 'debug',
      pathRewrite: {
        '^/api/boards': 'http://localhost:5001/api/boards',
      },
    }),
  );
};
```

`/api/boards` is api url example.
You can decide to change the api url.

Comment: It works fine when I use 'express' enviorment, but in my project I use the command 'npm run dev', it is http module only, how can I integrate this module function into my project when starting up the web project. Thanks!